# iFrame - Download with Changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I wanted to make a custom button that, when clicked, downloads my PDF document with the information currently filled out in the document. Chrome recently added this ability to "Download with Changes", but I can't figure out how to call this function. The button has id='download-edited', but I am very new to JS so having a hard time trying to create a button that directly links to this when called.

I also need the file download to pre-specified directory, if possible!

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: *Chrome recently added this ability to "Download with Changes", but I can't figure out how to call this function.* ... Is it a API level method or is it only just a new convenience feature of Chrome?

Comment: I am not 100% sure - but I also don't know if the ability to download an amended PDF is even possible. Very new to JS, so I'm googling like mad to figure this out. The download methods I've tried simply downloads the static file without changes made to the document in the browser

Comment: Do you know what version of Chrome this was released in?  The article I found that was published last year says it was in beta but not production:  https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/06/01/google-will-finally-make-it-easy-to-save-edited-pdfs-in-chrome/

Comment: I am currently on Version 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build)

Comment: I just watched their patch notes for version 99 and he didnt mention it:  https://youtu.be/h3mzFraS8CA  They are usually pretty good about documenting things.  I cant seem to find them mentioning the feature in a production release.

Comment: Strange - either way, it's there. You can test it yourself if you have a chrome browser. Would be great if we can leverage this feature and have a button on our page that invokes that function

Comment: I am very new to JS, but I figured this much as well - but is there a way to create a custom button for saving the annotated file? Thanks!